# Pull to refresh for UWP

Tags: xamarin, uwp, pull-to-refresh

Hi I would like to know if there are now ways to implement PullToRefresh functionality for UWP
i read and tried several blogs but it doesn't work for UWP. some of them were from 2016 - 2019 and they are saying that UWP doesn't support this functionality, so I would like to know if this is now supported, if yes, how?

I already tried. RefreshView / IsPullToRefreshEnabled but they are only working on Android and IOS.

Thanks!

Comment: The PullToRefresh function for UWP works only with touch, so we recommend that you can add a refresh button available for users who don't have a touch interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xamarin.Forms' own [RefreshView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/refreshview).

Like you can see in the documentation, you can even customise its direction:

> On the Universal Windows Platform, the pull direction of a RefreshView can be set with a platform-specific. For more information, see [RefreshView Pull Direction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/windows/refreshview-pulldirection).

Sample usage:

```xml
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:windows="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.WindowsSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core">
    <RefreshView windows:RefreshView.RefreshPullDirection="LeftToRight"
                 IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
                 Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}">
        <ScrollView>
            ...
        </ScrollView>
    </RefreshView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried testing this on windows desktop or windows device? I tried doing this but not working

Comment: Have you tested on a real device, or just on a simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Or [PullToRefreshListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/archive/pulltorefreshlistview). Only for UWP